# Gwibber notifications are not shown

Tags: 10.04, gwibber, notify-osd

Since the microblogging plugin for gnome.do fails to work in combination with a Proxy, I switched to Gwibber.

Gwibber works fine, but although 'Display notifications' is checked in my preferences, notifications are not shown.
All other notifications (like sound, pidgin) work fine.

I am using Lucid with all the latest updates and Gwibber version: 2.30.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- I don't believe Gwibber notifications are shown while the Gwibber window is open/visible. This isn't certain, but try closing the main window via the close button (not the quit option) and see if you start receiving notifications.
- With the Gwibber window closed, check to see that the `gwibber-service` process is still running, either in System Monitor, top, or `ps x | grep gwibber`. If it's not, something is wrong.
- If all else fails, please file a bug by running `ubuntu-bug gwibber`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a preference checkbox that will only notify you if someone is directly messaging you, you might want to make sure that box is *unchecked*.

[image]

Comment: Curse that box. I almost feel like it would be better to see three radio buttons: Show all notifications, show only mentions, and no notifications. Would simplify things a bit.

Comment: Eerily enough, today's Gwibber update in maverick does just that.

Comment: Yeah, we thought that was very confusing so fixed it in Maverick!